# Как отправить в DJANGO шаблон параметр текущей даты

Tags: django

Задача состоит чтоб показать список людей с сегодняшнем днем рождения

Не знаю как указать текущую дату в операторе IF.

```
personal_list.html

{% for personal in personals %}
{% ifequal personal.data_nastere|date:"d/m" '??/??' %}
    <ul>
        <li><a class="titleOmagiat" href="{% url 'personalomagiat_detail' pk=personal.pk %}">
         {{ personal.name }} {{ personal.surname }} </a>, {{ personal.birth_day|date:"d/m/Y" }}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}


Model.py

class Personal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    birth_day = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.name, self.surname)

view.py
def personal_list(request):
    personals = Personal.objects.order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'blog/personal_list.html', {'personals': personals})


url.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^personal/$', views.personal_list, name='personal_list'),
]
```

Просьба показать в коде, т.к. нахожусь на начальном пути.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные должны фильтроватся на уровне базы данных, чтоб сократить время обработки, поэтому view.py я переписал так

```
 from django.utils import timezone


 def personal_list(request):
     today = timezone.now().date()
     personals = Personal.objects.order_by('name').filter(
         birth_day__month=today.month,
         birth_day__day=today.day)
     return render(request, 'blog/personal_list.html', {'personals': personals})
```

а шаблон переписал так:

```
 <ul>
   {% for personal in personals %}
     <li><a class="titleOmagiat" href="{% url 'personalomagiat_detail' pk=personal.pk %}">
      {{ personal.name }} {{ personal.surname }} </a>, {{ personal.birth_day|date:"d/m/Y" }}
     </li>
   {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```